# Build LINQ query for One-to-One and filtering by child

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, linq, full-text-search

I have very simple model with two entities related as One-to-One via reference navigation properties:

```
class Post //"Main"
{
    public int RowId { get; set; }
    public string SomeInfo { get; set; }
    public FTSPost FTSPost { get; set; }
}

class FTSPost //"Child"
{
    public int RowId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Match { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's important but FTSPost represents virtual table of FTS5 SQLite and I'm following [this exmaple](https://www.bricelam.net/2020/08/08/sqlite-fts-and-efcore.html) so FTSPost is used for free text search capability. What I need to do is just to retrieve the whole rows of data from both tables based on the text search result and not just the text itself as in the example. I.e. I'm searching by `Content` of FTSPost and need to get respective `SomeInfo` of Post, not just `Content` itself. Note: `Match` is the service property which is used for searching and it's bound to the name of FTSPosts table. It works, so I can retrieve just `Content` as in the example.

The obvious (for me) query doesn't work, it yields zero results:

```
//Doesn't work! -- zero results :(

results = _context.Posts.Where(m => m.FTSPost.Match == "text for search"); 

SELECT *
FROM "Posts" AS "m"
LEFT JOIN "FTSPosts" AS "f" ON "m"."RowId" = "f"."RowId"
WHERE "f"."FTSPosts" = "text for search"
```

However, the following nice raw SQL query works well but I can't wrap my mind how to make it in LINQ! I tried to repeat it as is, with double "from" clauses but it converts to CROSS JOIN and doesn't work either. Please, help! P.S. I use EF Core 5.

```
//It works!! 

SELECT *
FROM "Posts" AS "m", "FTSPosts" AS "f"
WHERE "f"."FTSPosts" = "text for search" AND "m"."RowId" = "f"."RowId"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why "obvious" query didn't work was the way how the one-to-one relation was created. Even though the one-to-one seems to be mirrored, the way matters. After swaping `Message` and `FTSMessage` in the following code everything started to work. LEFT JOIN in the generated SQL query was replaced by INNER JOIN.

Correct code:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Message>(
            x =>
                {
                    x.HasOne(fts => fts.FTSMessage)
                     .WithOne(p => p.Message)
                     .HasForeignKey<Message>(p => p.RowId);
                });
```